# NetSuite Custom Segments for Access Retriction

Tags: netsuite

In NetSuite, I wanna confirm if there exists any method that I can set Custom Segments to roles Access Restriction, if not, any else method I can restrict role's data access by a customized column other than [department, class, location].
[image]

Any tips would help, Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To allow or restrcit access to a Custom Segment, set the values on the "Permissions" tab.  Refer to [Suite Answer Id 43334](https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/43334/kw/Custom%20Segment%20Permissions), step 14, the part on Permissions.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the NetSuite Support team had posted their opinion for my concern in enhancement: [356372](https://nlcorp.app.netsuite.com/app/site/hosting/scriptlet.nl?script=847&deploy=1&custpage_ervotingviewdetail=T&custpage_ervotingviewdetailissueid=34311602&custpage_votecount=57).